# Robustness diagram and design class diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram, domain-model, robustness

Currently, I'm creating a design class diagram from the domain class diagram. 
However, while searching for the examples I've found out Robustness diagram. 
 They look similarly as both of them have entity, control and boundary classes.
Are they the same? If I want to create design class diagram can consider examples of the robustness diagram
Or can someone gave an example of class diagram that includesentity, control and boundary classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Robustness diagrams](http://agilemodeling.com/artifacts/robustnessDiagram.htm) are not standard UML class diagrams. But they relate to the exact same concept of [Entity-Boundary-Control](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-control-boundary), which is an approach that was invented in the context of use-case driven development.

The idea behind ECB is to derive the design from the use-cases: entities are domain objects (i.e. they are relevant for the user and the business), controls correspond to use cases, and boundaries to the association of a use case with some actor (so it’s the interface with the outside world).

Robustness diagrams are meant to sketch the design without getting lost in overly complex class details. So it uses the stereotype icons (which was invented by Ivar Jacobson, together with ECB) instead of the class details with its internals.  And to facilitate the link, it also shows the actors (which are external to the system) and the use cases (the ECB are supposed to implement) in the same diagram.

In principle, remove the actors and use cases from a robustness diagram and you should have a decent class diagram.